# Why I cannot convert from int to string C# ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I get error message:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

```
var user = _db.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
var userRole = _db.UserRoles.ToList();
            var roles = _db.Roles.ToList();
            var role = userRole.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == user.Id);

            if (role != null)
            {
                user.Role = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == user.Role).Id;
            }
```

Ok, I get the point that I have from left side `int` and right side `string`. This is clear, but when I try to convert  all query to string like

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
if (role != null)
            {
                user.Role = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.ToString() == user.Role).Id.ToString();
            }
```

I also try something like

```
if (role != null)
            {
                user.Role = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == int.Parse(user.Role)).Id.ToString();
            }
```

And it throw exception:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's')

What I made wrong here ? Where is the mistake ?

Comment: `user.Role` is null. `int.Parse` is throwing an ArgumentException because you're passing it null, and the `u.Id.ToString() == user.Role` is always failing because `int.ToString()` never returns null (and then the `FirstOrDefault()` doesn't find any matching items, returns `null`, and accessing `.Id` on it throws a NullReferenceException)

Comment: @canton7 You are right !  What is the best way to solve this errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare strings don't do '==' but use String.Equals(string a, string b) this will take care of some problems for you. Then you need to check if the returned object is not null. If the FirstOrDefault Function returns null you do not have an object with the criteria in that collection.

Something like this should get you there:

```
if (role != null)
    {
        foundRole = roles.FirstOrDefault(u => string.Equals(u.Id.ToString(), User.Role))
        if(foundRole != null){user.Role = foundRole.Id.ToString())
    }
```

Another Hint: take care of the names of the variables. For me this seems very confusing:

- userRole = list of entities
- user.Role = is and ID?

Hope this helps!

Comment: "this will take care of some problems for you" -- like what, exactly? `==` [just calls `String.Equals`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Comparison.cs,737), they're the same thing!

Comment: @LedStarr Thank you for you answer, It help me !

Comment: I think the practical thing about it is that if you use a lot non-explicit declaration it is easier to spot if you compare the wrong type for example. Also you can add a comparisonType. @canton7 But you are right. There is no real difference.